# On third-person singulars in a step-form algorithm description

Tags: third-person

I wonder whether it is necessary to use third-person singulars for the verbs in the step-form algorithm description, which I explain now.

The first version is without third-person singulars.

> The algorithm A has the following steps:
>
> - Compute B=f(A).
> - Check whether g(B)=1.
> - Output h(B).

The second version uses third-person singulars.

> The algorithm A has the following steps:
>
> - ***Computes*** B=f(A).
> - ***Checks*** whether g(B)=1.
> - ***Outputs*** h(B).

Which one is more grammatically correct?

Comment: If the algorithm itself performs those functions, then you'd use the second version.  If you are giving someone step-by-step instructions on what they must do to carry out the algorithm's functions, then you'd use the first version.

Comment: @Billy Thanks, Billy. Does the second point you mentioned, _"give someone step-by-step instructions..."_, mean imperative mood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, we invariably use the plain form (*compute*, *check*, *output*). I imagine that this is because the algorithm is essentially a set of instructions, similar to those for a laboratory experiment, a recipe, etc., so it uses the imperative mood with an implied second-person subject; and indeed, although we often think of algorithms as being executed by computer programs, they are often executed by humans, and have been for millennia. (And that's not just from a modern perspective; the very word *algorithm* long predates computing machines.)

That said, if you prefer, you can probably just think of them as bare infinitive phrases; I can't imagine any algorithm steps being negated (imperative "don't X" vs. bare infinitive "not X") or referring directly to the reader ("While holding the array *A* in your left hand, slowly shuffle array *B* into it"), so for all intents and purposes that should be equivalent.

Comment: If the algorithms are running on servers, or the algorithm is a sub-algorithm run by another algorithm, does imperative mood still work here?

Comment: @WeikengChen: Yes. A *prose* description of an algorithm can use other forms (such as the present passive indicative), but a list-of-steps description always uses the plain form.